# command not properly ended error

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2

can i know what was the reasons for me to get the error of command not properly ended as i am not sure what the fault in the code

```
   delete 
   from usernamepassword join faculty_admininfo 
   on (usernamepassword.username = faculty_admininfo.email_address) 
   where faculty_admininfo.employee_id IN ('SCM-021232');
```

Comment: where in the Oracle manual did you find the `join` syntax for the delete statement?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support `JOIN` in `DELETE` clause. So your using JOIN in DELETE is the issue with your query.

You need to change your query to make use of `IN` or `EXISTS` instead.

You can make use of the below queries -

Using IN -

```
 DELETE 
   FROM usernamepassword WHERE username IN 
   (SELECT email_address FROM faculty_admininfo 
    WHERE employee_id IN ('SCM-021232'));
```

Using EXISTS -

```
DELETE 
   FROM usernamepassword unpwd WHERE EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 FROM faculty_admininfo info
    WHERE info.email_address = unpwd.username 
    AND info.employee_id IN ('SCM-021232'));
```